# How do I include the latest package updates in a customized LiveCD?

Tags: custom-distributions

Using the Ubuntu customization kit, is there a way to include all the updates on the created CD (up to the point when the CD gets created)?

Thanks

Comment: not sure about UCK.. but I think `remastersys` is right tool for this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can do this with the LiveCD by chrooting into the expanded squashfs filesystem and running apt-get with upgrade or dist-upgrade. Note that the repacked customized filesystem may not fit on a 700MB CD (run clean, delete apt caches, etc. anyway)

Comment: Many thanks for the accept, Mitch: I was typing this answer on the phone, I will update soon with some more detail and better formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Using ubuntu-defaults-builder, you can make your original iso image including update packages.

**Step1. Install ubuntu-defaults-builder**

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-defaults-builder
```

**Step2. Making Template**

```
ubuntu-defaults-template ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386
```

This command makes directory named ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386 within several files and some folders.

**Step3. Customizing Template**

In ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386 directory, hooks/chroot file is there.
Add below 3 lines to last part of the file.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade --yes
apt-get clean
```

If you want to localize, change i18n/language.txt, i18n/langpacks.txt, and i18n/keyboard.txt. Or if you want to add some applications, add package names into depends.txt in top of directory.

**Step4. Making DEB Package**

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

This command makes package named "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386_0.1_all.deb" in upper directory.

**Step5. Execute ubuntu-defaults-image**

```
cd ../
sudo ubuntu-defaults-image --package ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386_0.1_all.deb
```

This command makes iso image named "binary-hybrid.iso".

But this image is over 726MB, you should burn this iso image to DVD disc, or install this iso image to USB drive.